# HtmlEditor javafx lose focus

Tags: java, javafx

Any time I use `setHtmlText` method the `HtmlEditor` loses focus. How can I fix this?

```
htmlEditor.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        htmlEditor.setHtmlText(stripHTMLTags(htmlEditor.getHtmlText()));
        htmlEditor.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

I have tried this but still not working.